# I get LINQ to Entities Int32 ToInt32(System.String) when convert

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I get LINQ to Entities Int32 ToInt32(System.String) when convert.i tried int.Parse() , SqlFunction and EdmFunction but the problem still going on.

Exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Code:

```
try
    {
        ModelEntities me = new ModelEntities();
        var query = from p in me.Products
                    join c in me.ProductCategories
                    on Convert.ToInt32(p.CategoryId) equals c.CategoryId
                    select new
                    {
                        p.ProductTitle,
                        c.CategoryName
                    };
        rptProducts.DataSource = query;
        rptProducts.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Why is the category stored as a string in one place and an integer elsewhere? Looks like a code smell to me

Comment: can you change like-->`on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId.ToString()` assuming p.CategoryId is stringtype while c.CategoryId is int32type

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use Convert.ToInt32 inside your linq query. Linq has its own syntax and does not recognize external methods.

Either you have to extract the variable you are looking for to C#, convert it, and use it as a variable in another query. Or you could make both categoryIDs ints, if you have access to the database. It makes sense that similar fields like those should be of the same type.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know that you CAN do Convert.ToInt32(p.CategoryId) to a Linq query in Linqpad , I know for a fact, and I cannot fathom the genius behind Linqpad not abiding within LINQ /C# rules and api.    I had done a convert.toint32 in linqpad but then i had changed to have other value to .ToString() for my .net c# application.   Basically I am saying that specific C# operation of Convert.ToInt32 is just fine to what I know.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest converting c.CategoryId to string like this

```
 var query = from p in me.Products
             from c in me.ProductCategories
             let categoryId = me.ProductCategories.Take(1).Select(x => c.CategoryId).Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault()
             where p.CategoryId == categoryId 
             select new
             {
               p.ProductTitle,
               c.CategoryName
             };
```